# Entity with foreign key exception cached in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core code-first and in my case I have 2 tables `Doc` & `DocType`.

`DocType` is static and saved in the database. When I send wrong data from Swagger for `Doc` entity `{ Id = 1, DocTypeId = 0 }`, then I get a foreign key exception because there is no type with `Id = 0`.

After that I send correct data to EF Core, but EF Core seems to cache the last (wrong) data and sends both entities (last wrong and correct) to SQL Server and I get the same exception again.

```
public class Doc
{
   public int  Id { get; set; }
   public int DocTypeId { get; set; }
   public DocType DocTypeInclude { get; set; }
}

public class DocType
{
   public int  Id { get; set; }
   public int Title { get; set; }
   public List<Doc> DocList { get; set; }
}

public class DocConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Doc>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Doc> builder)
    {
         builder.HasOne(ba => ba.DocTypeInclude)
                .WithMany(b => b.DocList)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Doc_DocType")
                .HasForeignKey(ba => ba.DocTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}

public async Task AddAsync(Doc d)
{
    try
    {
        await this._dbContext.
        Doc.AddAsync(d);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is because you're using EF entity types as ASP.NET DTOs. Don't do that.

Comment: What is the scope of your DbContext?

Comment: @Dai I would agree for EF maybe, but not necessarily EF core, plus Asp.Net Core seems particularly designed / optimized to use EF Core DTOs directly, esp. in combination with OData.

Comment: @marsze OData is a special-case. Outside that, there's no difference between EF and EF Core.

Comment: DbContext has ChangeTracker.Clear(), Is it good idea use it on catch???